# Virtual Pet Games on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm planning to do a virtual pet game with various timers in the game (how often does hunger drop, and the energy system that alot of facebook games use.)

However, I'm thinking that if the user close the app, we won't be able to access the timer of the app right? So is it a must for a server to be available in other to make the app run smoothly.

One solution i thought of was using `[NSDate date]`, is it feasible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A better method is to store the important events, and use a timer in the game strictly to check for the next event. For instance, if the owner feed the dog, just write down that the dog got fed at that real time, and then have your timer fire every so often to see if enough time has passed to warrant making the dog hungry again. That way the actual state of the timer is irrelevant.

Also, this would mean that you don't need more than one timer. You would have a handler method that would look at your state, and trigger other methods as needed based on the amount of time since the last event.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking 1) The current time is stored. 2) The timer fires every second 3) The stored time is decremented by 1 second.  4) Find out if the time passed makes dog hungry again?  Whats the difference between this, a timer system and a counter system?  Also, you say its not affected by system time. I'm not so sure. What happens if the app is left for days and the user returns. Is this accounted for in this system?

Comment: It's not different, save that the time stored is a real time, and so you can compare it to another real time (like the current time), and compute the duration easily, while offline. No need for a server, or counting seconds.

Comment: Lets say current system time is 10.30. Dog needs feeding every 30 mins and has just been fed. The time of 10.30 is stored.  The events calendar says the dog should not be fed for another 30 mins. But what happens if I fast-forward the clock to 11.30 (in other words cheat the game).  Am I correct your idea would solve this, and if so how?

Comment: If you set the time forward, the game's timer ought to look at the list of past feedings, note that there is one past due (because there's an hour old feeding), and the game will complain that the dog is 30 minutes hungry. So, to describe the loop, it'd simply run down the list of past events, compare the time to now(), and run whatever actions would be due based on the current time, as if previous checks had run but been ignored. When the user feeds the dog, the old feeding event would be removed from the list.

Comment: An events system which relies heavily on system time can easily be cheated. Lets use the example of TinyTower - its has an events list/system, if you fast forward the clock the game would allow you to accure vast amounts of money because it subtracted the time of now() from the time of last play and calculated how much you were owed from all the various businesses.   I am not sure how a system like you describe would stop this.  If you could clarify that point I'd be most appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: It's a game, not a million dollar tournament. I wouldn't worry about such things. Many people who play with "The Sims" use the cheat codes more thn they play it straight, that makes it more fun. I'd not spend too much time worrying about cheating, rather spend time figure out more ways to be entertaining.

Answer (score 0):

If your pet game requires user to be on the app to play, you could always save the necessary details and reload them back when the user launches the app again. Otherwise, you probably need a server and do synchronization each time.

Comment: saving the details? my problem now is about the timer..meaning if the app is closed, i save the current timer state then when it's relaunched i compare the difference? and also, are these calculations allowed if app is running in background?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: In fact you should reschedule the timer when the app is relaunched. Even if you run it in background, the app can be terminated at any time when the OS requires more memory which may provide even more problems such as data unsaved or corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Computers are *really fast these days*.

An entire days-worth-of-stats can be generated lickity-split, even without using discrete formulas -- if the app isn't open then the pet doesn't need to "get hungrier" and **any stats changes or "daily events" can be generated as soon as the application is active again** -- no need to even worry about background events for an inactive application.

However, I suspect that for a more friendly game would use additional "soft" logic to encourage the user to play with the pet without having it starve to death during a business meeting: it's a game and games can make their own rules as long as the user keeps playing.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your question is more about how to get your timers to fire even while the app is closed. The answer is you don't. However, you can use local storage on the iPhone to store the most recent time that *event XYZ* occurred, and when the app starts up again next (say 1 day later), you can compare the current time with the most recently saved time, and quickly update the state before the user sees anything otherwise. The user will be none the wiser, and it will appear as if time actually elapsed within the game world.